# uninitialised value of size 8

Tags: c, initialization, valgrind

I am Running a code for valgrind

```
int fun(char* str) {
    char* prt1;
    char* ptr2;
    char sstr[20];

    strcpy(sstr, "\0");

    ptr1 = str;
    ptr2 = sstr;

    while (((isspace(*ptr1)) || (iscntrl(*ptr1))) && (*ptr1 != '\0'))
        ptr1++;

    while (*ptr1 != '\0')
        *ptr2++ = *ptr1++;

    while (((isspace(*(ptr2 - 1))) || (iscntrl(*(ptr2 - 1)))) && (ptr2 > str))
        ptr2++;

    *ptr2 = '\0' strcpy(str, (S8*)sstr);

    return (strlen(ptr1));
}
```

getting this error ***Use of uninitialised value of size 8***
for line

```
while (((isspace (*(ptr2-1))) || (iscntrl (*(ptr2-1)))) &&
     (ptr2 > str))
```

If i put the `NULLP` check before assigning to the pointers this is error is gone

```
if (ptr1 != NULLP && ptr2 != NULLP) {
    ptr1 = str;
    ptr2 = sstr;
}
```

Is it with Valgrind code error or the check should be included ?

Thanks for the help .

Comment: Please don't write `*(ptr-1)` when you mean `ptr[-1]`. We might run out of parentheses, you know.

Comment: after adding the null check still there is loop with *(ptr-1), why there is no error ?

Comment: the null check invokes UB and everything could happen after that

Answer (score 3):

No the check for NULLP is completely wrong and in fact invokes undefined behaviour as the pointers are not initialized at that time.

The real problem is that when you first enter the loop

```
while (((isspace (*(ptr2-1))) || (iscntrl (*(ptr2-1)))) && (ptr2 > str))
```

you check the last char copied, and if that's a white space or control character you increment `ptr2` and now you check the first char **you have never initialized**.
(left aside the fact that the condition also is wrong for the case that you haven't copied any character. Then `isspace(*(ptr2-1))` would invoke UB as well)

If you want to trim `sstr` (is it so?), your loop should be

```
while ( ptr2 > sstr && ( isspace (ptr2[-1]) || iscntrl (ptr2[-1]) ) )
    ptr2--;
```

Note the differences:

- compare `ptr2` with `sstr` instead of `str` and do it first, so that `isspace()` and `iscntrl()` are not executed if `ptr2 == sstr`
- `ptr2--` instead of `ptr2++`

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change this line:

```
while (((isspace (*(ptr2-1))) || (iscntrl (*(ptr2-1)))) && (ptr2 > str))
```

to this:

```
while ((ptr2 > str) && ((isspace (*(ptr2-1))) || (iscntrl (*(ptr2-1)))))
```

You won't get the error. It looks like you could be reading before the
beginning of `str`, since your check `ptr2 > str` will occur after the
dereference. Moving this check to the beginning of the conditional allows
it to short circuit.

Comment: only the first check would be ok, after `ptr2++` you still would check uninitialized characters

Comment: There seem to be multiple problems with this code fragment, I now notice that ptr2 is not even a pointer into str (it points to the sstr buffer).

Comment: that's ok I think as there is data copied from `ptr1` to `ptr2` but of course `ptr2 > str` should be `ptr2 > sstr`